# What does this python codes mean?

Tags: python

What does this python codes mean? New to python. THX!

```
  benchmark_sets_list = [
  '%s:  %s' %
  (set_name, benchmark_sets.BENCHMARK_SETS[set_name]['message'])
  for set_name in benchmark_sets.BENCHMARK_SETS]
```

Comment: Could you provide more context please?

Comment: means, someone does not know, how to program in python

Comment: How do you know?:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part...

```
for set_name in benchmark_sets.BENCHMARK_SETS
```

...will grab the set names from `benchmark_sets.BENCHMARK_SETS` and it will keep them one by one into a `set_name` variable.

After that, it will be able to know the values from this line...

```
(set_name, benchmark_sets.BENCHMARK_SETS[set_name]['message'])
```

...because `set_name` will have a value. That part will return two things, `set_name` and `benchmark_sets.BENCHMARK_SETS[set_name]['message']`. Probably those two things will be both strings.

Then, those `%s` you see in this line...

```
'%s:  %s' %
```

...will be replaced by the value of `set_name` and `benchmark_sets.BENCHMARK_SETS[set_name]['message']` respectively. That will generate an string like this one: "foo: bar", being "foo" the value of `set_name` and "bar" the value of `benchmark_sets.BENCHMARK_SETS[set_name]['message']`.

In order for you to understand what happened there, this is a simple example:

`"%s %s %s" % (first_elem, second_elem, third_elem)`

That code will replace the first `%s` with the value of `first_elem` The second `%s` with the value of `second_elem`, and the third `%s` with the value of `third_elem`.

And finally that string will be added to the list which is being constructed. So, at the end you will have an list more or less like this one:

```
["foo: bar", "wop: wap", "bing: bang"]
```

Comment: Thank you Vicente so much for such details! Now I understand.
Actually my questions is how do you python guys call this "cool" method of assigning values to a list(or array)?
Could you please give me a tutorial link?
Because in traditional way, there is always a for() or while() loop to do so

Comment: That is called "list comprehension" and it has the following syntax:
`L = [expression for variable in sequence]`. In your example, the "expression" is the `"%s: %s" % (...)` part. And then you have the `for set_name in whatever` part as well. I'm sure you are able to match your example code with that syntax :-) You can Google about "python list comprehension" and you will find tutorials and examples.

Comment: GREAT! Thank you so much! That's exactly what I want to know. 
I just jump into python codes, no time to do thoroughly study. It's readable for most parts. This is one exception:)

Comment: No problem. If you still have problems to understand how it works, look at this example: `doubles = [ x*2 for x in [1, 2, 3] ]`. That will generate this list: `[2, 4, 6]`. It will take the `1`, it will multiply it by two (`x*2`), and it will add it to the array that is being built. Then the same with the `2`, and finally with the `3`. Easy to understand :-)